# How to Access the website ( webforms ) from local nework using IIS

Tags: webforms, web-hosting

I made a web site using web forms in webmatrix, the site is working fine in local host.

But I would like access it from the local network using IIS.

Please help me..

Comment: You'll need to provide more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming that IIS supports the code and its working fine when you go to your browser and type localhost. You would have to open up command prompt and type "ipconfig" and get the ipaddress of your local machine. Next you open up that port that you are using in firewall and then go to another computer on the network and type the ip of the computer running the site. Hope this helps anyone else because i know that this is pretty late :)

Answer (score 0):

For that you should first RUN IIS Server in your PC.

To Enable IIS please refer the below link.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/365704/Install-IIS-on-Windows-7

And then you should add the Web Application ( Your Application ) to IIS.

To Add your site to IIS Please Refer the below link.

http://www.hosting.com/support/iis7/create-new-sites-in-iis-7/

And also it require web.conf